# Python Pandas Import Excel sheet cell as object without quotes in the end

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

My example excel sheet looks like this:

**Excel sheet data:**

customer1_data.xlsx =

```
parameter                                       customer1                   
analysis                                                1
analysis_name                             1month_services
analysis_duration                [2022-08-23, 2022-11-02]
analysis_numcheck                                      1
analysis_dupcolumns                                    1
```

**Import excel sheet data as dataframe** It looks normal but when I query individual rows or cells, some cell values have quotes at the end. I don't want any quotes in the end.

```
c1df = pd.read_excel('customer1_data.xlsx')
c1df.set_index('parameter',inplace=True)
print(c1df)

parameter                                       customer1                   
analysis                                                1
analysis_name                             1month_services
analysis_duration                [2022-08-23, 2022-11-02]
analysis_numcheck                                      1
analysis_dupcolumns                                    1
```

**Present output**
When I print individual cell values

```
print(c1df.loc['analysis'])
1

print(c1df.loc['analysis_duration'])
'[2022-08-23, 2022-11-02]'

print(c1df.loc['analysis_name'])
'1month_services'
```

**Expected output:**

```
print(c1df.loc['analysis'])
1

print(c1df.loc['analysis_duration'])
# I don't want any quotes at the end for the list here
[2022-08-23, 2022-11-02]

print(c1df.loc['analysis_name'])
# ' ' quote is expected for the string, no issues here
```

'1month_services'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to convert string delimited to lists :

```
c1df["customer1"]= (
                    c1df["customer1"].str.strip("[]")
                                     .str.split(",")
                        .where(c1df["customer1"].str.contains("[\[\]]", regex=True, na=False))
                        .fillna(c1df["customer1"])
                    )
​
```

##### # Output :

```
print(c1df)

             parameter                  customer1
0             analysis                          1
1        analysis_name            1month_services
2    analysis_duration  [2022-08-23,  2022-11-02]
3    analysis_numcheck                          1
4  analysis_dupcolumns                          1


print(c1df.iloc[2,1])
['2022-08-23', ' 2022-11-02']
```

Comment: Above solution works fine on dataframe. I have a series, so, made following changes to it: `series= (series.str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
        .where(series.str.contains('[\[\]]', regex=True, na=False))
        .fillna(series))`